# Type checkmark emoji without variant form

Tags: iphone, unicode, emoji

I use Notes on my iphone and mac. When I type an emoji checkmark on the mac it is text-sized (✔). However, when I type on my iphone and then view on my mac, the checkmark is larger (✔️), and increases the line spacing. Is there a way to type the smaller version on my iphone?

---

Extra info:

The small mark (✔) is unicode U+2714

The large mark (✔️) is unicode U+2714 U+FE0F

Comment: If anyone knows the best way to format the unicode in the question please do so.

Comment: What application do you use on your Mac to view the character you entered in your iPhone?

Comment: There are various apps for iOS that let you input specific unicode characters like Unicode Pad.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. macOS: Type the character in Notes.app on your Mac.
2. iOS: On your iPhone open the created note with the character. Select and copy it.
3. iOS: go to settings > general > keyboard > text replacement
4. Tap '+', paste the character to the first text field (Phrase) and an abbreviation for the small check mark in the second field (Shortcut).

To insert the small check mark in iOS just type the text shortcut you assigned in text replacement followed by a space.

——-

Please note:

If this should not work it is not an issue with the Unicode symbol but with the way the word processor adjusts for symbol characters. Please let us know what application on the Mac you are experiencing this issue with.

iOS check mark: ✔️

Comment: This works, thank you. It would be nice if I could use the large check mark emoji as the shortcut, but this gets the job done